# Cannot store std output of python script in command line as string

Tags: java, python, runtime

Shouldn't I be able to simply type "python" in my command line and retrieve the text that is spit out?

```
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String result = null;
        while ((result = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.println("<div>" + result + "</div>");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The desired result would be:

```
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: So what does it do *instead*?

Comment: Nothing. I don't even get an error. It just doesn't seem to want to interpret the python command from Runtime.

Comment: so it's stuck in the `while` loop, or it just finishes everything, or what?

Comment: If I run a command like `cmd /C dir` it works fine. It prints the standard output of the console. If I run a simple python command I literally get no stack trace. Nothing happens.

Comment: "nothing happens" is not true. Does the `while` loop get entered, does the `result = reader.readLine()) != null` get evaluated? Debug a bit, otherwise, it'll be impossible to help you.

Comment: There must be something I don't understand about command lines. Python seems to be a different kind of command, in that it opens a Python sub-terminal. I have no idea. Anyway, `python path/script.py` does exactly what I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `python C:\Users\Me\HelloWorld.py` executes the script and collects the standard output:

```
try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python C:\Users\Me\HelloWorld.py");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String result = null;
        while ((result = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.println("<div>" + result + "</div>");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```